# How do I make an Array from jSoup Elements? (java)

Tags: java, html, arrays, jsoup

How do I get the values in a piece of Html (values="valueIWant"), and have them in an Array ? 
I tried the following, but that didn't work:

```
HttpEntity entity5 = response5.getEntity();
    String defaultString = EntityUtils.toString(entity5);
    Document defaultDoc = Jsoup.parse(defaultString);                   
    Elements values = defaultDoc.getElementsByAttribute("value"); //DropDownList Values
    String s[] = {""};
    for(int a=0; a<values.size(); a++){
        s[a] = values.get(a).toString();
    }
    return s;
```

So anyone got an answer? thanks. (Btw, i use Jsoup)

Comment: "that did not work"... In what way? Did you get compilation error, runtime exception, results did not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: is your HTML parsed correctly? Can you provide the contents of `defaultString`? Is `defaultDoc` valid is there a problem with file encodings perhaps?

Assuming `getElementsByAttribute` actually returns some objects —note that you have a typo, `value` instead of `values`— you're currently populating the array with the descriptions of all `Element`-objects, not the values of the attribute. Try something like the following:

```
int i = 0;
String s[] = new String[values.size()];
for(Element el : values){
    s[i++] = el.attr("values");
}
```

Comment: I now changed my code to
----Elements values = defaultDoc.getElementsByTag("option"); s[i++] = el.attr("value");---- I thought that it was "value" instead of "values", since <option value="VALUEIWANT"> says "value" (wich I wanted to get). Correct me if i'm wrong pls.

Comment: Then it's `value` indeed, however in your question you talk about `values`. However does your code work now? It should or other things may go wrong.