# Excluding two id's in jsoup selector?

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

I am trying to find all the input values of a url, but I need to exclude a couple. How do you exclude two or more id's in the list?
Similar to this:

```
        Elements e = doc.select("input[id != fm-login-id]");
```

but I want to exclude two id's, so I'm looking for something like this:

```
        Elements e = doc.select("input[id != fm-login-id && id fm-login-password]");
```

Does anyone know the proper way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if jsoup actually supports `[attr!=value]` selectors (they are [part of jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904473/having-trouble-with-attribute-selector/17904563#17904563), and I don't know how much jsoup borrows from it aside from `:has()`), but in standard selector syntax you do this with `:not()`, and either ID selectors or attribute selectors depending on your preference:

```
Elements e = doc.select("input:not(#fm-login-id):not(#fm-login-password)");
```

```
Elements e = doc.select("input:not([id=fm-login-id]):not([id=fm-login-password])");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Do you know if there is a way to parse all the "value" attributes from this elements list? Using  `System.out.print(e.attr("value"));` only gives one value from the first element. Does this mean I have to create an array?

Comment: @sandra burgle: You will need to loop through e (which itself is an array) with `for (Element element : e)`.

Comment: Thanks for help again! [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128984/how-do-i-make-an-array-from-jsoup-elements-java)(and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)) is what I found after I read your comment. Works great, for anybody who has same problem.